# Ajax Submit with AM Forms - How To

Tags: ajax, plugin-amforms

Is it possible to submit to an AM Forms form via Ajax? I cannot find anything in the docs? Is there a tutorial somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue open over on their [Github](https://github.com/am-impact/amforms/), asking about this and the last answer says it's something they are going to add at a later date.

[Ajax Sending Issue](https://github.com/am-impact/amforms/issues/144)

So, in short I guess not for the time being.

Edit: I guess if you have the time and fancy the challenge, you could always add it yourself and do a Pull Request?

Comment: Thanks Steve, since I don't have any php skills. I guess I'll have to wait to get that added.